# Nginx rewrite url with hash or md5

Tags: nginx

My cms creates html files for caching based on their url. To prevent too many files in one directory, in inserts a slash after the thrid character.

So for example:

- the url `/some-text-article-4711` is md5 hashed to `88c7966ed723feb1cb4a83b48f723c56` and the cms stores the html file under `88c/7966ed723feb1cb4a83b48f723c56`
- the url `/some-text/post-123` is md5 hashed to `8abfab6e4ab585984cc7fe53e129ee4d` and the cms stores the html file under `8ab/fab6e4ab585984cc7fe53e129ee4d`

Right now, the cms handles requests on (for example) `/some-text-article-4711` and outputs the content of `88c/7966ed723feb1cb4a83b48f723c56`. But it would be more efficent, if nginx could handle this without PHP.

Is there a way in nginx, to rewrite these requests to the correct form so it could serve these "static" files?

I can also change md5 to another hashing logic. The only reason for md5 is the "too many files in directory" probleme, since there are 100k+ urls under "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a great use case for njs.

https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/

In your case I would create a variable using `js_set` or `js_var`.

Create a njs function that will calculate the md5 hash based on the uri and add the slash between the third and the fourth positions. You can then use a rewrite rule to rewrite the uri OR use `try_files` to get file from disk.

For a set of njs examples see https://github.com/xeioex/njs-examples/tree/master/njs/http

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Right now, is a bit hard to install additional nginx modules, since its a plesk server :(

Comment: without any modules it will be hart to do. But as long as you have root access to the server you can simply load the dynamic module? should be a big deal.

Comment: I have now compiled and loaded the module. Tried out the hello world example from your link. it worked ;) I am now trying to create a "hash" function or so

Comment: Good to hear! Let me know if you need any help. Github Issue, Mailing List or my Discord (check my profile). Happy NJSing :D